# Transform XML to an (X)HTML version

Tags: java, html, xml, jsf-2, jdom

I have made a html table representation of som shop items from a cloud server. It works just fine with getting the string and interger elements using JDOM, but one of the elements, called itemDescription, in the Cloud XML is more complex because it contains further more elements and i can't figure out how to transform this to html, so that the text is presented as descriped (list, item, bold and italics)

Example of the CLOUD XML:

```
<w:item><w:itemID>6368</w:itemID><w:itemName>Samsung TV</w:itemName><w:itemURL>www.samsung.com</w:itemURL><w:itemPrice>1500</w:itemPrice><w:itemStock>28</w:itemStock><w:itemDescription><w:document xmlns:w="http://www.cs.au.dk/dWebTek/2014">
        This
        <w:italics>authentic</w:italics>
         tv has several advantages:
        <w:list>
            <w:item>it is cool looking</w:item>
            <w:item>
                it is
                <w:bold>black</w:bold>
            </w:item>
            <w:item>it can be used in all kinds of weather</w:item>
        </w:list>
    </w:document></w:itemDescription></w:item>
```

The application is based on JSF and here is how i generate the table. The tag `<w:hello>` is a custom tag where the transformed xml should be placed.

```
<table border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Adjust</th>
        </tr>
        <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{itemListBean.items}"
            varStatus="status">


            <tr>
                <td>#{item.itemID}</td>
                <td>#{item.itemName}</td>
                <td><w:hello></w:hello></td>
                <td><a href="#{item.itemURL}"><img src="#{item.itemURL}" width="200 px"></img></a></td>
                <td>#{item.itemPrice}</td>
                <td>#{item.itemStock}</td>
                <td><a href="adjust.xhtml?id=#{item.itemID}">Adjust</a></td>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </table>
```

The hello custom tag is handled by the HelloComponent.java

```
@FacesComponent("dk.au.cs.dwebtek.hello")
public class HelloComponent extends UIComponentBase {
public String getFamily() {
    return "dk.au.cs.dwebtek.hello";}

public void encodeBegin(FacesContext arg0) throws IOException {
    super.encodeBegin(arg0);
}
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.startElement("p", this);
    writer.write("Hello");
    writer.startElement("b", this);
    writer.write("World!");
    writer.endElement("b");
    writer.endElement("p");
}
}
```

The itemListBean (called in the repeat tag) returns an ArrayList of all the items in the shop. Here is how it is generated:

```
        ......
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        response = builder.build(con.getInputStream());
        ArrayList<Element> elementList = new ArrayList<Element>();
        elementList.addAll(response.getRootElement().getChildren());

        for (Element e : elementList) {
            String itemID = e.getChildText("itemID", ns);
            String itemName = e.getChildText("itemName", ns);
            String itemURL = e.getChildText("itemURL", ns);
            String itemPrice = e.getChildText("itemPrice", ns);
            String itemStock = e.getChildText("itemStock", ns);
            //Element description = e.getChild("itemDescription", ns);
            //String itemDescription = itemDescriptionReader.getTextContent(description);
            Item item = new Item(itemID, itemName, itemURL, itemPrice, itemStock, "itemDescription");
            itemList.add(item);
        }
        return itemList;
        .........
```

The custom tag works fine. I just need an example of how to transform the itemDescription element from the Cloud XML, into the custom tag, so that it is properly presented.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those technologies, but have you ever considered transforming XML to XHTML with XSLT?

Comment: Since it is a handin there are some limitations like: "Use JDOM to transform the Cloud XML itemDescription to an (X)HTML version that can be rendered in the browser and create a custom JSF tag to insert the value in a template." But i'll remember XSLT for another time - Thanks!